# javascript regexp greediness and groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of the form

```
'some text1<span class="  prefix-style1">some text2<span class=" prefix-style2 ">some text3</span>some text4</span>some text5<span class=" prefix-style3 ">some text6</span>'
```

I'm trying to turn it to:

```
line='some text1<style1>some text2<style2>some text3</>some text4</>some text5<style3>some text6</>'

That is remove all the 'span class="' words and the 'prefix' and turn </span> to </>
```

I tried:

```
line = line.replace(/<span class="\s*prefix-(.+)\s*">/g, '<$1>');
line = line.replace(/<\/span>/g, '<\/>');
```

However this does not work .. seems the regexp greediness spoils it and I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: be, non-greedy `line.replace(/<span class="\s*prefix-(.+?)\s*">/g, '<$1>');`

Comment: thx  Avinash, if ypost an answer I can approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to Avinash comment the solution is to use a non-greedy qualifier:

```
line.replace(/<span class="\s*prefix-(.+?)\s*">/g, '<$1>');
```